# Changing tkinter's Text widget font without overriding existing text(only future text)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, text, colors, tagging

**Minimal reproducible example code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import colorchooser

root = tk.Tk()

# iterate and increment count to create indexed tag names
count = 0

# creates a function that colors text selection and no text selection
def color_picker():
    global count
    # creates the color picker prompt
    color = tk.colorchooser.askcolor()

    # color text selection
    if text_area.tag_ranges('sel'):
        text_area.tag_add('colortag_' + str(count), tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST)
        text_area.tag_config('colortag_' + str(count), foreground=color[1])

        count += 1

    # color untagged text in case of no text selection
    else:
        text_area.config(foreground=color[1])


# the used field for typing text
text_area = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=1)
text_area.pack()

# new button to invoke color_picker()
color_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Pick color', command=color_picker).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Desired result:** I am looking for options where if no text is selected only future text's font color would change.

**Current result:** When no text selection is made both future text's font color changes and past text.

**Update #1:** I've been considering tagging text per key press, any one has an idea for the viability and the syntax of such a solution? Optimally it could be applied to Bold, Highlight, Overstrike and Underline.. For the latter the first index could be toggling Bold on and last index toggling Bold off?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please provide a complete [mcve]. When you use `tag_add`, it will always only affect text that has that tag.

Comment: I will try to create a program using the guidelines Bryan Oakley linked later today.

Comment: what does all of the code related to dragging items have to do with this question? Also, I don't think we need nearly a dozen buttons to reproduce this problem.

Comment: I will edit out all of that when I have a substitute, as I said in my comment, I will create a program using the guidelines you've linked as soon as possible. :)

for now I was hoping it would give a way to at least run the code.

Comment: @BryanOakley Is this any better? :)

Comment: Are you trying to mimic the "bold" button on a word processor - it either bolds the selected text or turns on "bold mode"?

Comment: Yes, sounds about right.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hey, man. Any idea regarding this matter?
Thanks in advance.